# Can i sell my own software that uses parts of PSEXEC

Tags: licensing, remote-desktop

I just have a quick licensing question about PSEXEC by sysinternals.

As some of you may know if you have ever used PSEXEC, it is confusing to learn at first. I have created a program that makes it easier to use, and was wondering if I am allowed to sell that program (even if PSEXEC is included with it?). I looked in the sysinternals license agreement, but couldn't really find the answer to my question.

The agreement is here: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb469936

The main download and info page for PSEXEC is here: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb469936

Please let me know if I will be allowed to sell my program.

(I assume i am on the right stackexchange site, but let me know if I should move my question)

Thanks!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is asking for interpretation of a third party license.

Answer (score 4):

I am no lawyer, but from the agreement:

> You may not:
>
> - ...
> - rent, lease or lend the software;
> - transfer the software or this agreement to any third party;

Makes it pretty clear that selling it is a no-go.

Anyways, psexec uses pretty standard API calls to do its work, you'd be better off just reimplementing it, in fact I think they used to have, and still might, a doc explaining just how all the sysinternals tools worked.